# Solving a nonlinear PDE with Mathematica10 FEM Solver

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a system of coupled nonlinear PDEs in a rectangular region with the new FEM solver in Mathematica 10. However, I come across an error stating

> NDSolveValue::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve.

Is there any workaround? I find it hard to believe that this task should not be possible. 
Do I have to adjust the method of the solver?

Here is my complete code:

```
Ω = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}];
pdes = {-Inactive[Laplacian][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 
    0.6*u[t, x, y] - u[t, x, y]^3 - v[t, x, y], 
    -Inactive[Laplacian][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] ==
     1.5*u[t, x, y] - 2*v[t, x, y]};
c = {
   (** ic **)
   u[0, x, y] == Exp[-5 ((x - 3/2)^2 + (y - 3/2)^2)],
   v[0, x, y] == Exp[-5 ((x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2)]
   (** blank bc = noflux **)
   };
{usol, vsol} = NDSolveValue[{pdes, c},
   {u, v}, 
   {x, y} ∈ Ω,
   {t, 0, 2 π}
   ];
```

Comment: Currently (V10.3) NDSolve can not handle non linear PDEs with the FEM  (it can via other method). There is an [example of how to write a non linear FEM solver](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96579/18437) with the [low level FEM functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you replace your input with

```
pdes = {-Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, x, y] - Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, x, y] 
    + Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 0.6*u[t, x, y] - u[t, x, y]^3 - v[t, x, y], 
    -Derivative[0, 0, 2][v][t, x, y] - Derivative[0, 2, 0][v][t, x, y] + 
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] == 1.5*u[t, x, y] - 2*v[t, x, y]};

c = {
      (** ic **)

   u[0, x, y] == Exp[-5 ((x - 3/2)^2 + (y - 3/2)^2)],
      v[0, x, y] == Exp[-5 ((x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2)]
      (** blank bc = noflux **)
      };
{usol, vsol} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pdes, c}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 2 π}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 
    2}];
```

> NDSolveValue::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.
>
> NDSolveValue::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable y. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.
>
> NDSolveValue::mxst: Maximum number of 14516 steps reached at the point t == 2.9421825263433456`
>
> NDSolveValue::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 577.1533477585843`at t = 2.9421825263433456` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 35 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options.

But you get something back. However, you'd need to specify boundary conditions to get something decent.

Concerning FEM, no, currently (V10) can not deal with non-linear stuff out of the box, it will in a future version. You can, however, use the [low level FEM functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html) to code one up your self today. Give that a shot. There is an [example of how to write a non linear FEM solver](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96579/18437).

Comment: That is somewhat disappointing... What does "future version" mean? Version 10.1 or 13.0? What are the low level FEM functions you are referring to?

Comment: @Oscillum, I don't know. Writing a non-linear solve that works generally from scratch is not entirely trivial. If you provide a problem set that works with `NDSolve` on a rectangular region it could be possible to write such a non-linear solve with the low level FEM functions. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Oscillum, added a link to the [low level fem functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html)

Comment: @m_goldberg, is there a tool to do the formatting?

Comment: Yes, ax excellent browser plug-in written by halirutan. Here is a [link](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/3066)

Comment: @m_goldberg, excellent thanks.

Comment: Since the answer seems to be that there is no answer, I accept yours ;) I hope I have some free time to burn soon, then I will try the low level fem functions. Maybe they even work for non-rectangular boundaries.

Comment: @Oscillum, I'd first think about the missing boundary condition. Then, if you want to use the FEM functions, you'd need to linearize your equations. Create a mesh and construct and interpolating function with the initial guess. Plug that into the coefficient of your linearized PDE, solve and make a new interpolation from the solution. Continue until it has converged.

Comment: Is FEM a must?  I have had a lot of success with non linear PDEs with NDSolve.  Yes, you will have to deal with stiffness but the Method->LSODA is quite the "golden hammer" for stiff non linear problems.

Comment: @Oscillon the "future version" is not out in 2017

Answer (score 6):

In Version 12.0 you can solve this:

```
pdes = {-Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, x, y] - 
     Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
     Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 
    0.6*u[t, x, y] - u[t, x, y]^3 - 
     v[t, x, y], -Derivative[0, 0, 2][v][t, x, y] - 
     Derivative[0, 2, 0][v][t, x, y] + 
     Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] == 1.5*u[t, x, y] - 2*v[t, x, y]};

c = {(**ic**)
   u[0, x, y] == Exp[-5 ((x - 3/2)^2 + (y - 3/2)^2)], 
       v[0, x, y] == Exp[-5 ((x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2)]
       (**blank bc=noflux**)};

{usol, vsol} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pdes, c}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 
    2}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];
Plot3D[usol[2 \[Pi], x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]