# Solving a coupled nonlinear PDE using low level FEM programming

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear, finite-element-method

Inspired by [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94914/nonlinear-fem-solver-for-navier-stokes-equations-in-2d/96579#96579) we try to solve this diffusion reaction problem using low level FEM

[image: these are the equations with known velocity fields]

we start defining a mesh and the utility function

```
  Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
    Domain = ImplicitRegion[
       0 <= x <= 1.25*10^-2 && 0 <= y <= 1*10^-2, {x, y}];
    meshA = ToElementMesh[Domain, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.0007}, 
      "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.0002]
    meshA["Wireframe"]

    PDEtoMatrix[{pde_, Ga_}, u_, r_] := 
 Module[{ndstate, feData, sd, bcData, methodData, 
   pdeData}, {ndstate} = 
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[Flatten[{pde, Ga}], u, Sequence @@ {r}];
  sd = ndstate["SolutionData"][[1]];
  feData = ndstate["FiniteElementData"];
  pdeData = feData["PDECoefficientData"];
  bcData = feData["BoundaryConditionData"];
  methodData = feData["FEMMethodData"];
  {DiscretizePDE[pdeData, methodData, sd], 
   DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcData, methodData, sd], sd, 
   methodData}]
```

[image]

after that our equations setup

```
Tin = 550;
pre = 10^4;
Ea = 5000*1000;
R = 1.986*1000;
k = pre*Exp[-Ea/Tin/R];
a = 0.5;
Ga = 3*10^-8;
fm = {.15, .10};
Rho = 1000;
PM0 = {24, 28};
CaZ = Rho*fm[[1]]/PM0[[1]];
CbZ = Rho*fm[[2]]/PM0[[2]];
Vx[x_, y_] := -a*(x - (1.25*10^-2)/2);
Vy[x_, y_] := a*(y - 0.005);
pde = {D[Ca[x, y]*Vx[x, y], x] + D[Ca[x, y]*Vy[x, y], y] - 
     Ga*D[Ca [x, y], {x, 2}] - Ga*D[Ca [x, y], {y, 2}] == 0, 
   D[Cb[x, y]*Vx[x, y], x] + D[Cb[x, y]*Vy[x, y], y] - 
     Ga*D[Cb [x, y], {x, 2}] - Ga*D[Cb [x, y], {y, 2}] == 0};
bds = {DirichletCondition[Ca[x, y] == CaZ, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[Ca[x, y] == 0, x == 1.25*10^-2], 
   DirichletCondition[Cb[x, y] == CbZ, x == 1.25*10^-2], 
   DirichletCondition[Cb[x, y] == 0, x == 0]};
```

we proced processing the linear part

```
{dPDE, dBC, sd, md} = 
  PDEtoMatrix[{pde, bds}, {Ca, Cb}, {x, y} \[Element] meshA, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {Ca -> 2, Cb -> 2}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> False, 
       "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}];

linearLoad = dPDE["LoadVector"];
linearStiffness = dPDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
vd = md["VariableData"];
offsets = md["IncidentOffsets"];
```

until here nothing wrong, we successful solve the linear part in the past, we proced now to the tricky iterative linearization

```
uOld = ConstantArray[{0.}, md["DegreesOfFreedom"]];
mesh2 = md["ElementMesh"];
mesh1 = MeshOrderAlteration[mesh2, 1];

ClearAll[rhs]
rhs[t_?NumericQ, ut_] := Module[{uOld}, uOld = ut;
  Do[ClearAll[Ca0, Cb0];

   (*create functions interpolations*)
   Ca0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh2}, 
     uOld[[offsets[[1]] + 1 ;; offsets[[2]]]]];
   Cb0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh2}, 
     uOld[[offsets[[2]] + 1 ;; offsets[[3]]]]];

   (*these are the linearized coefficients*)
   nlPdeCoeff = 
    InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
     "ConvectionCoefficients" -> {{{Vx[x, y], Vy[x, y]},{0,0}},{{0, 0}, {Vx[x, y], Vy[x, y]}}}, 
     "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{{{-Ga, 0}, {0, -Ga}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}, {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{-Ga, 
    0}, {0, -Ga}}}}, 
     "ReactionCoefficients" -> {{k*Cb0[x,y], 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0},{0,k*Ca0[x,y]}}];

   nlsys = DiscretizePDE[nlPdeCoeff, md, sd];
   nlLoad = nlsys["LoadVector"];
   nlStiffness = nlsys["StiffnessMatrix"];
   ns = nlStiffness + linearStiffness;
   nl = nlLoad + linearLoad;
   DeployBoundaryConditions[{nl, ns}, dBC];
   diriPos = dBC["DirichletRows"];
   nl[[diriPos]] = nl[[diriPos]] - uOld[[diriPos]];

   dU = LinearSolve[N[ns], N[nl]];
   Print[i, " Residual: ", Norm[nl, Infinity], "  Correction: ", 
    Norm[dU, Infinity]];
   uOld = uOld + dU;
   If[Norm[dU, Infinity] < 10^-6, Break[]];, {i, 8}];
      uOld]
```

we run this and nothing happend

```
   uNew = rhs[0, uOld];
```

the problem its how to write the coefficents exactly and why the LinearSolve is unable to find solution after hours run. We understand how the [iterative procedure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94914/nonlinear-fem-solver-for-navier-stokes-equations-in-2d/96579#96579) works, but we are not shure that we are applying the low level language in the right way.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a similar problem,[see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151087/solving-a-system-of-transient-non-linear-reaction-diffusion-pdes-over-a-region) could you help me by explaining the Vx and Vy terms here?

Answer (score 10):

This not a complete answer, but you `ReactionCoefficients` do not have to correct shape I think:

```
nlPdeCoeff = 
  InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
   "ConvectionCoefficients" -> {{{Vx[x, y], Vy[x, y]}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 
       0}, {Vx[x, y], Vy[x, y]}}}
   , "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{{{-Ga, 0}, {0, -Ga}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 
        0}}}, {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{-Ga, 0}, {0, -Ga}}}}
   , "ReactionCoefficients" -> {{k*Cb0[x, y], 0}, {0, k*Ca0[x, y]}}
   ];
```

Also, note that `PDEtoMatrix` does not take options, so the call should be:

```
{dPDE, dBC, sd, md} = 
 PDEtoMatrix[{pde, bds}, {Ca, Cb}, {x, y} \[Element] meshA];
```

And in the non-linear loop I'd use `meshA` in place of `mesh2`.

If we implement these changes and plot the outcome:

```
ca = ElementMeshInterpolation[{meshA}, 
   uNew[[offsets[[1]] + 1 ;; offsets[[2]]]]];
cb = ElementMeshInterpolation[{meshA}, 
   uNew[[offsets[[2]] + 1 ;; offsets[[3]]]]];
Plot3D[{ca[x, y], cb[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] Domain, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

we get:

[image]

Hope that get's you in the right direction. To make things a little simpler, you could try to first implement a Picard (fix-point) iteration. See [this and related lectures](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/videos.676.31.65.html).

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140822/18437) is an example with a single dependent variable, perhaps useful.

Answer (score 7):

In version 12 you can directly solve this; just add the nonlinear term:

```
Domain = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1.25*10^-2, 1*10^-2}];
Tin = 550;
pre = 10^4;
Ea = 5000*1000;
R = 1.986*1000;
k = pre*Exp[-Ea/Tin/R];
a = 0.5;
Ga = 3*10^-8;
fm = {.15, .10};
Rho = 1000;
PM0 = {24, 28};
CaZ = Rho*fm[[1]]/PM0[[1]];
CbZ = Rho*fm[[2]]/PM0[[2]];
Vx[x_, y_] := -a*(x - (1.25*10^-2)/2);
Vy[x_, y_] := a*(y - 0.005);
pde = {
   D[Ca[x, y]*Vx[x, y], x] + D[Ca[x, y]*Vy[x, y], y] - 
     Ga*D[Ca[x, y], {x, 2}] - Ga*D[Ca[x, y], {y, 2}] + 
     k Ca[x, y]*Cb[x, y] == 0, 
   D[Cb[x, y]*Vx[x, y], x] + D[Cb[x, y]*Vy[x, y], y] - 
     Ga*D[Cb[x, y], {x, 2}] - Ga*D[Cb[x, y], {y, 2}] + 
     k Ca[x, y]*Cb[x, y] == 0
   };
bds = {DirichletCondition[Ca[x, y] == CaZ, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[Ca[x, y] == 0, x == 1.25*10^-2], 
   DirichletCondition[Cb[x, y] == CbZ, x == 1.25*10^-2], 
   DirichletCondition[Cb[x, y] == 0, x == 0]};
```

Solve:

```
{CaSol, CbSol} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pde, bds}, {Ca, Cb}, {x, y} \[Element] Domain];
```

And visualize:

```
Plot3D[{CaSol[x, y], CbSol[x, y]}, Element[{x, y}, Domain]]
```

[image]

Mesh refinement works in the same way as before.