# How to create a fluid animation like this?

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, fluid-dynamics

When two fluids move past each other at different speeds, complex instabilities arise that look really cool:

[image]

The Navier-Stokes equations are numerically intense but can usually predict what will happen, is there any good way to plot these bi-fluid fractals with Dynamics?

These are related questions, but don't show how to generate an efficient `Animate[]` or GIF:

- [Solver for unsteady flow with the use of the Navier-Stokes and Mathematica FEM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180959/solver-for-unsteady-flow-with-the-use-of-the-navier-stokes-and-mathematica-fem)
- [Nonlinear FEM Solver for Navier-Stokes equations in 2D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94914/nonlinear-fem-solver-for-navier-stokes-equations-in-2d)

Comment: What is the source of the image?

Comment: If you just want to solve Navier-Stokes as a function of time and plot the solutions, user21 and others have shown how to do that here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nonlinear FEM Solver for Navier-Stokes equations in 2D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94914/nonlinear-fem-solver-for-navier-stokes-equations-in-2d). Perhaps see also: [Solver for unsteady flow with the use of the Navier-Stokes and Mathematica FEM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180959/27951)

Comment: @MarcoB not really, becuase I'm asking for an effcient dynamic visual, but that could be used to generate something like that

Comment: @C.E. https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematician-makes-euler-equations-blow-up-20191218/

Answer (score 15):

We cannot accurately reproduce what is shown in the animation, since the initial data are unknown. We can show a similar mixing process at the boundary of two oncoming flows. We use FEM and the NSE integration method described in [Solver for unsteady flow with the use of the Navier-Stokes and Mathematica FEM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180959/solver-for-unsteady-flow-with-the-use-of-the-navier-stokes-and-mathematica-fem).

Calculation of the velocity:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
k0 = Pi; L = 5; eps = 10^(-3);
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2*L, L}];
k = 70; ν = 5/10^3; t0 = 1/400; f = TranslationTransform[{2*L, 0}];
bcP = {
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == -1, v[x, y] == 0}, y == 0 && eps <= x <= 2*L - eps],
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 1, v[x, y] == 0}, y == L && eps <= x <= 2*L - eps],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == 0, f],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], x == 0, f]};
UX[0][x_, y_] := Tanh[k0*(y - L/2)];
VY[0][x_, y_] := 0.3*Sin[k0*x]*Sin[Pi*(y/L)]^2;
P0[0][x_, y_] := 0;
Do[
  {UX[i], VY[i], P0[i]} =
    NDSolveValue[
     {
       {
         Inactive[Div][{{-μ, 0}, {0, -μ}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y] + (u[x, y] - UX[i - 1][x, y])/t0 + UX[i - 1][x, y] D[u[x, y], x] + VY[i - 1][x, y] D[u[x, y], y],
         Inactive[Div][{{-μ, 0}, {0, -μ}}.Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y] + (v[x, y] - VY[i - 1][x, y])/t0 + UX[i - 1][x, y] D[v[x, y], x] + VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], y],
         Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] + Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y]
       } == {0, 0, 0} /. μ -> ν,
       bcP, DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == P0[i - 1][x, y], x == 2*L || x == 0]
     },
     {u, v, p},
     Element[{x, y}, reg],
     Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.02}}
    ],
  {i, 1, k}
];
```

Interface function diffusion calculation:

```
cn[0][x_, y_] := Tanh[k0 (y - L/2)];
Do[cn[i] = 
   NDSolveValue[{.3 ν (D[c[x, y], x, x] + 
         D[c[x, y], y, y]) == (c[x, y] - cn[i - 1][x, y]) + 
       UX[i - 1][x, y] D[c[x, y], x] + VY[i - 1][x, y] D[c[x, y], y], 
     DirichletCondition[c[x, y] == -1, y == 0 && eps <= x <= 2 L - eps], 
     DirichletCondition[c[x, y] == 1, y == L && eps <= x <= 2 L - eps], 
     PeriodicBoundaryCondition[c[x, y], x == 0, f]}, 
    c, {x, y} ∈ reg, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {c -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.02}}];, {i, 1, k}]
```

Create frames and animations:

```
frame = Table[
   ContourPlot[cn[i][x, y], {x, 3, 6}, {y, 1.75, 3.25} , 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
    Frame -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
    Contours -> Table[j^2 Sign[j], {j, -1, 1, .1}], 
    ContourShading -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> Green], {i, 0, k, 1}];

Export["C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\cnu03_9.gif", frame, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image: Figure 1]