# What's wrong with definition/visualization of a rectangular region (ImplicitRegion)

Tags: regions

In a very simple example I try to define a rectangular region

```
u = 1/Sqrt[2]; 
reg = ImplicitRegion[(-1 <= x <= 1 + u) && (-1 <= y <= 0 ) , {x, y}] 
RegionPlot[ reg  ]
```

[image]

Obviously the plot isn't complete.

What's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised that it returned anything. The documentation for `RegionPlot` shows its argument as a predicate rather than a region. For example, `RegionPlot[reg[[1]], {x, -1, 1 + u}, {y, -1, 0}]`. For the region use `Region[reg, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, but documentation of `ImplicitRegion` show several examples like  `\[ScriptCapitalR] =ImplicitRegion[
   x^6 - 5 x^4 y + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 + 3 x^2 y^4 - y^5 + y^6 ==0, {x, y}];RegionPlot[\[ScriptCapitalR]]`

Comment: Repeatable in version 12.0 on Win 10 Ent. Post to WRI support to see if it is a bug.

Comment: I can confirm the issue on V12.0.0 (macOS). `DiscretizeRegion[reg, Frame -> True]` and `RegionMeasure[reg]` work correctly though.

Comment: I discovered these flaws of `RegionPlot[]` back in version 11.3 - see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180959/solver-for-unsteady-flow-with-the-use-of-the-navier-stokes-and-mathematica-fem

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for the very interesting link. I've to elaborate...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> "Symbolic"}` work for this case.

```
u = 1/Sqrt[2];
reg = ImplicitRegion[(-1 <= x <= 1 + u) && (-1 <= y <= 0), {x, y}]
RegionPlot[reg, Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> "Symbolic"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this option