2D momentum type equation for compressible fluids
I have this program which displays errors in the declaration of terms, I've tried to modify it several times but it displays the same errors, apparently in the declaration of the term $(v \cdot \nabla)\cdot v $ and also in  $div(\rho v)$ it considers that $\rho v$ is not a vector, whereas it is.
The problem concerns a 2D mementum equation in a rectangular domain.
The program is next:
(* Parameters *)
d = 1; (* Diffusion coefficient for rho *)
mu = 1; (* Viscosity coefficient *)
tau = 1; (* Relaxation time *)
alpha = 1; (* Parameter alpha for P(rho) *)
vmax = 1; (* Maximum velocity *)
(* Define the normalized Euclidean distance to the target escape *)
target = {10, 2.5}; (* Target escape coordinates *)
nu[x_, y_] := Norm[{x, y} - target]/Norm[target];


(* Initial conditions *)
rho0[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]; (* Initial density *)
v0[x_, y_] := {0, 0}; (* Initial velocity *)

(* Define the domain *)
Ω = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}];
Γout = RegionBoundary[Ω];
Γw = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}}];
region = RegionDifference[Γout, Γw];

(* Define the Lamb vector *)
Lamb[u_, {x_, y_}] := 
  Curl[u, {x, y}] // Simplify;(* Curl gives the vector {0,0,Curl[Z, {x, y}]}, so we only need the last component *)

(* Define the equations *)
eqns = {
   D[rho[t, x, y], t] == 
    d Laplacian[rho[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
     Div[(rho[t, x, y] v[t, x, y]), {x, y}],
   D[v[t, x, y], t] == 
    mu Laplacian[v[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
     Div[v[t, x, y].Grad[v[t, x, y]], {x, y}] + 
     1/tau (rho[t, x, y] nu[x, y] - v[t, x, y]) - 
     Grad[rho[t, x, y]^alpha, {x, y}] - Lamb[v[t, x, y], {x, y}]
   };

(* Boundary conditions *)
bc = {
   DirichletCondition[rho[t, x, y] == rho0[x, y], True],
   DirichletCondition[v[t, x, y] == v0[x, y], True],
   DirichletCondition[rho[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0 || y == 0],
   DirichletCondition[v[t, x, y] == {vmax, 0}, x == 2 || y == 2]
   };

(* Solve the equations *)
{solrho, solv} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqns, bc}, {rho, v}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} ∈ Ω];

(* Plot density and velocity *)
Plot3D[solrho[1, x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "rho"}, PlotLabel -> "Density"]
VectorPlot[solv[1, x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
 VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, # &}, 
 VectorPoints -> 10, PlotLabel -> "Velocity"]


@andre314 thak you for the remark. Now there is a more precise title.

Gradient has 2 or 3 arguments, not 1. Then you need initial conditions.

@DanielHuber Of course, and this is my question, v(t,x,y) is by definition a 2-component vector, so do I have to define it using two components? i.e. v(t,x,y)=(v_1(t,x,y),v_2(t,x,y))*. Otherwise, there is initial conditions rho0[x_, y_] & v0[x_, y_] := {0,
0}

I do not see any initial conditions in your code.  It is possible that MMA recognizes that rho and v are vectors from the initial conditions. If not, you have to specify rho and v elementwise.

Function nu[x,y] is not defined. There is typo with Grad[v[t, x, y]] definition, it should be Grad[v[t, x, y],{x,y}]. We need to define vector v before Div and Grad, otherwise we have message Div::sclr: The scalar expression rho[t,x,y] v[t,x,y] does not have a divergence.

@AlexTrounev Thank you for your answer. In fact, I've now added the nu[x_,y_] function to the edited code. So, if I understand correctly, we need to define v[t,x_,y_] as {v1[t,x_,y_], v2[t,x_,y_]} so that the Div and Grad functions are well defined now?  I note that the first heat equation is a scalar and the second velocity equation is a 2D vector function. My second question is it possible to solve this problem in Mathematica 12 ?

@KamalKhalil Yes, we can solve this system with some options like it described here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180959/solver-for-unsteady-flow-with-the-use-of-the-navier-stokes-and-mathematica-fem

@AlexTrounev OK, thanks. The references are to 2D compressible N-S equations, I understand. But I'm saying that the compressible form might be easier to code it using  NDSolve since we don't have pressure P as a variable (here is given by rho^\alpha), and I'm saying that it might look like a coupled system of parabolic PDEs since we have the diffusion and viscosity parameters.

@KamalKhalil Please, see my answer.

Did you see the FuildFlowPDEComponent?

@user21 Yes I see it thank you very much, but the problem is solved for me.

This problem can be solved with NDSolve as follows
(*Parameters*)d = 1; (*Diffusion coefficient for rho*)
mu = 1; (*Viscosity coefficient*)
tau = 1; (*Relaxation time*)
alpha = 1; (*Parameter alpha for P(rho)*)
vmax = 1; (*Maximum velocity*)
(*Define the normalized Euclidean distance to the target escape*)
target = {10, 2.5}; (*Target escape coordinates*)
nu[x_, y_] := Norm[{x, y} - target]/Norm[target];


(*Initial conditions*)
rho0[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]; (*Initial density*)
v0 = {0, 0}; (*Initial velocity*)

(*Define the domain*)
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}];
\[CapitalGamma]out = RegionBoundary[\[CapitalOmega]];
\[CapitalGamma]w = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}}];
region = RegionDifference[\[CapitalGamma]out, \[CapitalGamma]w];

(*Define the Lamb vector*)
Lamb[u_, {x_, y_}] := 
  Curl[u, {x, y}] // 
   Simplify;(*Curl gives the vector {0,0,Curl[Z,{x,y}]},so we only \
need the last component*)
v = {v1[t, x, y], v2[t, x, y]};
(*Define the equations*)
eqns = {D[rho[t, x, y], t] == 
    d  Laplacian[rho[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
     Div[(rho[t, x, y]  v), {x, y}], 
   Thread[D[v, t] == 
     mu  Laplacian[v, {x, y}] - Div[v . Grad[v, {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
      1/tau  (rho[t, x, y]  nu[x, y] - v) - 
      Grad[rho[t, x, y]^alpha, {x, y}] - Lamb[v, {x, y}]]};

(*Boundary conditions*)
bc = {DirichletCondition[rho[t, x, y] == rho0[x, y], True], 
   DirichletCondition[{v1[t, x, y] == v0[[1]], 
     v2[t, x, y] == v0[[2]]}, True], 
   DirichletCondition[rho[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0 || y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{v1[t, x, y] == If[t < 10^-4, 0, vmax] , 
     v2[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 2 || y == 2]};
ic = {rho[0, x, y] == rho0[x, y], v1[0, x, y] == 0, 
   v2[0, x, y] == 0};
(*Solve the equations*)
{Rho, V1, V2} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqns, bc, ic}, {rho, v1, v2}, {t, 0, 
    1}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];

Visualization
(*Plot density and velocity*)
{Plot3D[Rho[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "rho"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Density", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", MeshStyle -> Yellow],
 StreamDensityPlot[{V1[1, x, y], 
   V2[1, x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, # &}, StreamPoints -> Fine, 
  PlotLabel -> "Velocity", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]}



The program works well. Thank you very much for you collaboration.

You are welcome!
